# Can not upload file with data by guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

I want to upload a file with data parameter, but it do not work.

```
$client->post('http://xxx/', [
    'json' => [
        'abc' => 'abc'
    ],
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'file',
            'contents' => fopen('xxx.sh', 'r')
        ]
    ],
]);
```

It only post abc parameter. And it only can post file when I delete json parameter.
I want to upload file and post some data in one request, How can I do that?

Comment: FYI. I have opened an issue asking about mixing request types other than form_params. https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1386

Answer (score 0):

Note
multipart cannot be used with the form_params option. You will need to use one or the other. Use form_params for application/x-www-form-urlencoded requests, and multipart for multipart/form-data requests.

from: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#multipart

do this:

```
$response = $client->post('http://example.com/api', [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'image',
            'contents' => fopen('/path/to/image', 'r')
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'name',
            'contents' => 'Example name'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

from: [Guzzle ~6.0 multipart and form_params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645996/guzzle-6-0-multipart-and-form-params)

done.

Comment: He is not using form_params, he is using JSON Request Option. http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#json

Answer (score 0):

In order to send the JSON information, it will have to be sent with the Multipart message. Multipart cannot be mixed with any other body related request option. Verification from the owner of Guzzle: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1386