# Guzzle post nested array Issue

Tags: laravel, curl, xdebug, guzzle

I develop website using Laravel 5.5 and Guzzle 6.3.

I encountered a problem when trying to guzzle post nested arrays when trying to do create folder to BOX using API.

```
$url = $this->api_url . "/folders";
$headers = [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->access_token,        
];
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->post($url, [
    'headers' => $headers, 
    'form_params' => [
        'name' => $name,
        'parent' => [
            'id' => $parent_id
        ]
    ]
]);
```

It shows me errors like this:

> Entity body should be a correctly nested resource attribute name/value pair

I also already tried using `shell_exec` curl so it run curl from command prompt and it gives me same error like this

[image: picture]

But when I tried to run from cygwin the curl works fine.

I also can do upload using multipart request nested array works fine.

I don't know why I'm getting with this nested array issue when the nested array works fine with multipart request.

Reference for box documentation POST [is here](https://developer.box.com/v2.0/reference#create-a-new-folder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#form-params) you can't use the multipart option:

> form_params cannot be used with the multipart option. You will need to use one or the other. Use form_params for application/x-www-form-urlencoded requests, and multipart for multipart/form-data requests.
>
> This option cannot be used with body, multipart, or json

So maybe try to set the header when creating the Client instance:

```
$url = $this->api_url . "/folders";

$client = new Client([
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->access_token,
        'Accept'        => 'application/json',        
    ]
]);

$response = $client->post($url, [ 
    'json' => [
        'name' => $name,
        'parent' => [
            'id' => $parent_id
        ]
    ]
]);
```

actually after reading box reference again, post request without files upload it accepts application/json ,
which is form_params used for application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: yes i do understand form_params cannot be used with the multipart option,
i already tried what you mentioned, its still gave me the same error
https://developer.box.com/v2.0/reference#create-a-new-folder
i knew it doesnt need multipart

I only mention , my code/my curl for uploading it also has nested array and it works perfectly fine

Comment: okay i figure it out with your advice , i will edit your suggestion

Comment: then maybe the problem is that you are passing an associative array for the parent. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30753498/8374833) might help you

Comment: yes your first suggestion actually half correct, 
move out the headers to invoke guzzle
and then add application json
and change form_params to json
thanks for help Daniel !

Answer (score 1):

For you to make any http request of data containing nested fields; you must include `Content-Type` on the headers; then set it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` like so:

```
$url = $this->api_url . "/folders";
$headers = [
    'Accept'       => 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->access_token,
];
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->post($url, [
    'headers' => $headers,
    'form_params' => [
        'name' => $name,
        'parent' => [
            'id' => $parent_id
        ]
    ]
]);
```