# How to upload file via Guzzle HTTP in Laravel

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I am configuring my Guzzle Request like this:

```
try {
   return json_decode($this->client->request('POST', https://example.com/store, $this->getOptions($data))->getBody()->getContents(), true);
        } catch (GuzzleException $e) {
               echo $e;
}
```

Set up my Header and Data like this:

```
private function getOptions($data = null)
{
    $options['headers'] = [
       'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
       'Accept'       => 'application/json'
    ];
    if ($data) {
       $options['form_params'] = $data;
       $options['json']        = $data;
    }
    return $options;
}
```

File is not sending. What is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Guzzle ~6.0 multipart and form\_params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645996/guzzle-6-0-multipart-and-form-params)

Comment: where is your file?